# PIN Prompt for SmartCard in c#

Tags: c#, cryptography, smartcard

I'm trying to write an application that prompts for a PIN and then verifies user certificate using smart card.

I successfully read the certificates in my smart card, but I can't get the smart card to ask me for the PIN, thus making impossible for me further development such as using the smart card to sign a document, using my PIN.
In order to read the certificates, I set up my custom CSP, then I imported `advapi32.dll` functions (`CryptAcquireContext`, `CryptGetProvParam`, `CryptReleaseContext`). Then I'm able to read the key containers and so on.
The only information I don't know how to implement is how to ask for a PIN.

I read on Microsoft documentation that I need to call `CryptGetProvParam`, and that the PIN is accessible using `PP_ADMIN_PIN`. But honestly I'm lost trying to using it. Could somebody explain how to use `PP_ADMIN_PIN` and `CryptGetProvParam` together?

Comment: I think the question is OK, but asking for sample code on this site is asking for trouble, so I removed that part of the question for you.